# My domain name is pointing to different places on difference device

Tags: dns

I bought the domain from GoDaddy and hosting from Hostgator. I am using that domain as the add-on domain in the Hostgator. I have updated the nameserver of HostGator in GoDaddy 30 hours before. It got propagated. But on some devices, it is showing the website content in Hostgator, but on other devices, it shows the GoDaddy page. I do not know what is the issue. i have cleared the cache, restarted the device, did everything but nothing solved the issue

Comment: did you remember to increment the SOA serial number? if you share the domain I can do a couple of lookups for you.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to say that i do not know what is mean by SOA serial number.If you give the right link i will learn that. My problem got solved by the following way. when i ping the website, i did not get the IP address of my hosting. Then i flushed the DNS through cmd. Then the website loaded. Thanks for the reply.

Could anyone say what is the IP address that i got before the flush. Is that belongs to domain registrars (GoDaddy)?